# Need some help with Scala's instance variables

Tags: java, oop, scala, language-features

Assume this Java code:

```
public class A {
   public A(String g) {
      x += g.length();
   }

   private int x = 0;
}
```

If I create an instance of A, like this:

```
A a = new A("geo");
```

after this call, the value of x will be 3. What am I doing wrong in my Scala code?

```
class A(val g:String) {
  x += g.length
  var x:Int = 0
}

object x extends Application {
  val x = new A("geo")
  println(x.x)
}
```

This prints 0. I assumed that when the compiler reaches the `var x:Int = 0`, the body of the main constructor has ended. Am I wrong? How else could you declare instance variables in Scala ( assuming I don't want them in my constructor ) ?

Comment: Every line of code that is not inside a def (method body) is constructor code. Val and var initialization code is included in that and the constructor is the top-to-bottom accumulation of all that code. Note that this includes things like method *calls* interspersed between val, var and def *definitions*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that your code translates into something similar (but not exactly) to this:

```
public class A {

  private final String g;
  private int x;

  public A(String g) {
    this.g = g;
    x_$eq(x() + g.length());
    x = 0;
  }

  public void x_$eq(int arg0) {
    x = arg0;
  }

  public int x() {
    return x;
  }

  public String g() {
    return g;
  }
}
```

But vars defined in (non-constructor) methods get translated into actual local variables.

Not sure if this explains the reasoning so much as highlights one of the differences.

---

**EDIT** - Changed "translation" from scala to java for clarity and ability to more accurately represent what is happening.

Comment: So, why wasn't `_x` 3? That's how I'm reading the code representation.

Comment: But how is `x` treated? As a local variable? Is the compiler declaring it?

Comment: The var x is in instance variable in all cases. With the declaration var x: Int = 0, the variable x is a private variable with public x() and x_=() methods automatically created.

Answer (score 7):

Your confusion results from a misunderstanding of how constructors in Scala works. Specifically, let's translate the Scala code you posted into Java:

```
class A(val g:String) {
  x += g.length
  var x:Int = 0
}
```

becomes

```
public class A {
   public A(String g) {
      x += g.length();
      x = 0;
   }
   private int x;
}
```

The reason is simple. The whole body of a class in Scala is the primary constructor for that class. That means the statements in it, and initializing `val` and `var` are statements, will be executed in the order they are found.

PS: Here is the actual, true rendition of that code.

**Scala 2.7**

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas> scalac -print A.scala
[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: A.scala
package <empty> {
  class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    @remote def $tag(): Int = scala.ScalaObject$class.$tag(A.this);
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val g: java.lang.String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def g(): java.lang.String = A.this.g;
    private[this] var x: Int = _;
    <accessor> def x(): Int = A.this.x;
    <accessor> def x_=(x$1: Int): Unit = A.this.x = x$1;
    def this(g: java.lang.String): A = {
      A.this.g = g;
      A.super.this();
      A.this.x_=(A.this.x().+(g.length()));
      A.this.x = 0;
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

**Scala 2.8**

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scala\Programas>scalac -print A.scala
[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: A.scala
package <empty> {
  class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    <paramaccessor> private[this] val g: java.lang.String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def g(): java.lang.String = A.this.g;
    private[this] var x: Int = _;
    <accessor> def x(): Int = A.this.x;
    <accessor> def x_=(x$1: Int): Unit = A.this.x = x$1;
    def this(g: java.lang.String): A = {
      A.this.g = g;
      A.super.this();
      A.this.x_=(A.this.x().+(g.length()));
      A.this.x = 0;
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good to see you have as much difficulty as me free-handing java without slipping in scala-isms.  You missed a semi-colon and used the non-existent-in-java underscore initializer.

Comment: Ok, code fixed, and compiled to make sure. Why can't Java be reasonable? :-)

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, though I see you offered a superior answer (ie, a more accurate translation into Java).

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
class A(val g:String) {
  x += g.length
  var x:Int = 0
}
```

to

```
class A(val g:String) {
  var x = g.length

}
```

Comment: Why not just make it a `val`?  There's no evidence from the sample code that it needs to be modified.

Answer (score 4):

var x:Int = 0 
make this the first line of the constructor

```
class A(val g:String) {  
   var x:Int = 0  
   x += g.length  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does Scala let you reference `x` before you declared it? In any other scope, this would be illegal.

```
scala> def foo(g:String) = { x+=1; var x=0; x}
<console>:4: error: forward reference extends over definition of variable x
       def foo(g:String) = { x+=1; var x=0; x}
```